# Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to Any

Tags: swift, string, option-type

I have some error like this "Expression implicitly coerced from `String?` to `Any`" this is my code :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FIRApp.configure()
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: "myemail@gmail.com", password: "mypassword", completion: { (user, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(user?.email)
        }else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })

    return true
}
```

Error in this line

```
print(user?.email)
```

And

```
print(error?.localizedDescription)
```

Please help me

Comment: You can do `user?.email as Any` to explicitly state that you want it to convert to `Any`

Answer (score 51):

The `print` function requires a set of `Any` parameters. `String` is a `Any`. In this case Xcode is telling you that it implicitly coerced the optional string into an `Any` object (by transforming the `String` value in `Optional(value)`).

To avoid this warning, you can simply use a default value or unwrap the `String?`

```
print(user?.email ?? "User instance is nil")
print(user!.email)
```

Comment: What will happen is user is nil on the second line?

Comment: The app will crash, of course. But after my explanation about Optional I think it was implicit

Comment: what  a monkey job to write every time ?? "" atleast or getting ur app crash becaus of prints. why cant it just print nil where it became nil and thats it?

Comment: @ZaporozhchenkoAleksandr I totally agree with you, but my answer scope is to explain why the error happens and how to get rid of it. The best way to do it, you find it.

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti yes, sure. thats was just complaints about native api ;) thx for what you've done

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti (Caveat: I'm new to Swift.) Isn't it also true that `Optional<String>` is an `Any`?  If so, why does it complain when we pass it an `Any` in the form of an `Optional<String>`?

Comment: One more option for this issue is explicitly cast to Any. `user?.email as Any`.