# Why is it necessary to coerce from Optional to Any?

Tags: swift, option-type

I have seen several questions regarding "expression implicitly coerced from an `Optional` to `Any`"(such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691184/expression-implicitly-coerced-from-string-to-any) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386836/swift-3-expression-implicitly-coerced-from-uiview-to-any)), but I did not find one explaining the reason why `Optional` is not "included" in `Any`, since, according to the Apple's Swift Standard Library, `Optional` is a generic `enum` type.

`Any` parameters are expected for the `print` function, so providing `Optional` would give the warning message. However, since `Optional` is an enum type, shouldn't it be an `Any` type as well? Why is `Optional`, as an enum type, not part of the `Any` type such that the compiler needs to convert `Optional` to `Any`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `Optional` is to prevent you from accidentally calling methods on or accessing properties of variables which are `nil`.

You are right that `Optional` can be assigned to `Any`. Anything can be assigned to `Any`. But look what happens now! I have transformed a value that can be `nil` into a non-optional type `Any`! If somehow this value is passed to somewhere else and some other programmer (or you in the future) would assume that it has a non-nil value.

Therefore, the compiler warning is there to remind you that you may have forgotten to unwrap your optionals.

Comment: The actual reason (SE-0140) was the bridging between Objective-C `id` and `Any`, as pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508680/1187415.